# Let $T:\ell_1 \to c_0$ be linear operator defined as $x_n \to \sum_{k\geqslant n} x_k$. Then $T \in B(\ell_1, c_0)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I'm solving some exercises for my Functional Analysis Exam. Here is one on which I am stuck:

> Let $T: l_1 \to c_0$ be linear operator defined as $x_n \to \sum_{k\geqslant n} x_k$. Show that $T \in B(\ell_1,c_0)$ and compute $T^*$,the adjoint of $T$

Of course $T \in B(\ell_1,c_0)$ and $\| T \| \leqslant 1$. But I am unable to find the adjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\varphi \in c_0^{\ast}, \exists y\in \ell^1$ such that
$$
\varphi((x_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_ny_n
$$
Then
$$
T^{\ast}(\varphi)((x_n)) = \varphi(T(x_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} x_k\right) y_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \left(\sum_{k=1}^n y_k \right) =: \psi((x_n))
$$
Hence, $T^{\ast}(\varphi) = \psi$ where $\psi$ is as above.

If you identify $c_0^{\ast} \cong \ell^1$ and $\ell^1 \cong \ell^{\infty}$, then one can write $T^{\ast} : \ell^1 \to \ell^{\infty}$ by
$$
T^{\ast}((y_n)) = (z_n) \text{ where } z_n = \sum_{k=1}^n y_k
$$
Note that
$$
|z_n| \leq \|y\|_1 \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
and hence $T^{\ast} \in B(\ell^1, \ell^{\infty})$ with $\|T^{\ast}\| \leq 1$.

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: I think you have computed transpose of $T$ instead of adjoint of $T$.Is there some relation between adjoint and transpose?Thanks

Comment: How is the adjoint defined?

Comment: I think the adjoint which I have in mind makes sense only for Hilbert spaces and of course $l^1$ is not Hilbsrt space.So In Normed spaced do we also call transpose to be adjoint?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes.

Comment: I see..Your solution is quite neat and of course deserves +1.Thank you!